# nosetests: error: no such option: --with-doctest

Tags: python, nose, doctest

I am trying to run all doctests in all modules, but get the following result:

```
$ nosetests --with-doctest
Usage: nosetests [options]

nosetests: error: no such option: --with-doctest
```

Something is crashing but it's hard to say what exactly. I have fixed all failures shown by `nosetests --with-doctest -vvv` but it didn't help.

Any idea how to debug it?

`nose==1.3.0`

**UPDATE:**

Running with `py.test` was more pleasant in this case and showed failing tests without crashing:

```
py.test --doctest-modules
```

I still don't know what happened with nose.

Answer (score 2):

After fixing failing tests with `py.test`, it started to crash in the same way `py.test: error: no such option: --doctest-modules`, but it provided a bit better error message and it stroke me that `optparse.OptionParser` was not protected by `if __name__ == "__main__":`. Now tests work fine for both `nose` and `py.test`.

Comment: Just hit this as well. Super confusing. I don't think I would have figured it out on my own. 